# Custom Graphics in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, graphics, ide

I am looking to develop a JavaFX  application that will be a graphical code editor.

In this editor, I will generate an interconnecting set of icons and graphics and press a button to take the graphics generated by the user and output some code

I don't want to use Bitmaps for my Icons and though I can draw lines, shapes and curves, I would ideally like to contain these all combined in an object that can be returned to the canvas to draw - although I cannot find the wrapper I have to use.

Has anyone got any examples or reccomend an aproach i can use?  I'm happy with the code generation routines, just not building the graphical editor in JavaFX

Thank you
Alan

Answer (score 0):

VRL Studio is an excellent free and open source example of a graphical code editor written in JavaFX. It is amazing.

https://github.com/VRL-Studio/VRL-Studio

Take a look at it for examples on what you want to do. If I were you I would not attempt to reinvent the wheel... Rather extend from this open source framework.

Comment: Looks good, I'll have a look into this although I was hoping to know what approaches to take for a basic implementation rather than bring in a separate framework / library.